# recursive function that takes a pointer to the middle of an infinite doubly linked list and Search for a key

Tags: c++, recursion, doubly-linked-list

Provide a recursive function that takes a pointer to the middle of an infinite
doubly linked list along with an integer key and searches the list for the given key. The
list grows infinitely in both directions. Your algorithm should be able to find the key if it is
present in the list, otherwise it should continue the search infinitely.
This is The question i'm provided with and i can't understand how To recursivly search on both sides. either i'll have to write 2 functions i.e one for searching left other for right side.
but can it e searched in one function?
this is my code:

```
 void searchmiddle(Node<T>* middle, int key,int index) {
       
        if (middle == NULL) {
            return  ;
        }
        if (head == NULL) {
            return  ;
        }
       /* if (middle->next == head) {
            return false ;
        }*/
        if (middle->data == key) {
            cout << "key found at  index "<<index << endl;
            key = 0;
            return ;
        }
        searchmiddle(middle->prev, key, index - 1);

         searchmiddle(middle->next, key, index + 1);
         


    }
```

code works for key next to middle pointer..

Comment: Recursion seems like the _worst_ to use in this scenario. Sidenote: `int key` should probably be `const T& key`

Comment: *"otherwise it should continue the search infinitely"*: since a stack is finite and usually very limited, you should certainly **not** use recursion for fulfilling this requirement.

Comment: but is there a way to search both ways simultaneously using recursion?

Comment: *"simultaneously"* ? not without threading or some other async. I'm still curious what the super-mystery `head` has to do with any of this.

Comment: If your list is **not** growing infinitely, yes, then it is of course possible to search in two directions in tandem using recursion, but that is not the challenge you have put forward, so the answer is: **don't** use recursion.

Comment: @TedLyngmo *"... along with an integer key."* I suspect that wasn't by accident.

Comment: BTW, what is the use of the `index` parameter? It is not mentioned in your description. And why is your function a void function? Shouldn't it return some result to the caller?

Comment: @WhozCraig It could be a problem if `T` is `long long`

Comment: if we use circular doubly linked list ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I guess I didn't say that right. The instructions specifically state they provided key is integer. Perhaps overtly optimistic, but that seems the reason the OP chose that as the `key` type. Frankly, I'm surmising this question is as poorly written as it is instructional.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, OP needs to learn that _integer_ doesn't necessarily mean `int`. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo or the instructor needs to learn to write clearer questions for the students they're supposed to be teaching. Probably both.

Comment: I have to sumbit the assignment m question is is there a way to actually search in both ways at same time

Comment: Sure, just relay the call to a function that takes two `Node<T>*` (`left` and `right`) then check if any of them is the correct one. If not, call the same function again recursively with `left->prev, right->next` ... You start by calling it with `middle, middle`. It could look [tlike this](https://godbolt.org/z/T1bPEz6qc) - but searching in linked lists using recursion is a bad idea and even worse when it's stated that the linked list is infinitely long...

Comment: @nitrations Did any of the answers help? If you need clarifications, please just ask in the comment field under the answer you have questions about.

Answer (score 1):

You could relay the call to a function that instead takes two `Node<T>*`, `left` and `right`. You then check if either one is the correct node and return if anyone is, otherwise you call the same function again recursively while stepping both `left` and `right.

```cpp
template<class T>
Node<T>* searchmiddle(Node<T>* left,  Node<T>* right, const T& key) {
    if (left->data == key) return left;
    if (right->data == key) return right;
    return searchmiddle(left->prev, right->next, key);   
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* searchmiddle(Node<T>* middle, const T& key) {
    return searchmiddle(middle, middle->next, key);
}
```

This is purely theoretical though since it'll most probably stop working when the stack is full. It also doesn't check for `nullptr` since the list is said to be infinite.

Nothing in the requirement says anything about printing an index so I made it return a pointer to the found `Node<T>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use recursion, because the requirement is that the search should continue infinitely for as long as there is no match. The call stack is limited, and recursion consumes it, meaning the recursion cannot go on indefinitely.

By consequence, the search should happen through iteration and not recursion.

You should use two pointers, one that will move along the `prev` pointers to the left, and the other that will move along the `next` pointers to the right. As apparently it is needed to report the *index* where the match was found, you should accompany those two pointers with an index.

There should not be a reference to a `head` pointer (where is it defined?), as an *infinite* list has no `head`. The challenge description suggests that the list extends continually in both directions, so there will be no end node like a *head* or a *tail*.

The code could be something like this:

```
void searchmiddle(Node<T>* middle, int key, int index) {
    Node<T>* left = middle;
    int leftIndex = index;
    Node<T>* right = middle->next;
    int rightIndex = index + 1;

    while (1) { // Search continues as long there is no match
        if (left->data == key) {
            cout << "key found at  index " << leftIndex << endl;
            return;
        }
        left = left->prev;
        leftIndex--;
        
        if (right->data == key) {
            cout << "key found at  index " << rightIndex << endl;
            return;
        }
        right = right->prev;
        rightIndex++;
    }
}
```

This is quite a theoretical challenge, as the only way to have a really infinite linked list, is to make it circular. It also means that there is a possibility that the key will never be found giving you a function that never finishes.